# Recursion and Loop

Tags: java, c++, loops, recursion

There is something, which I am not quite sure about it.

Let's say we got a function called foo, which looks something like

```
void foo(Parameter a1) {
   if(condition == true)
       return;             // jumping out of recursion

   for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

      if(contion == true)
          foo(a1);         // calls itself

      ...
   }
   ...
}
```

What I'd like to know is, when the function foo() calls itself and say this happens a few times. Does the counter i always start at 0 or not? I mean everytime the function is called by the function itself.

I would appreciate if someone could explain me that.

Comment: Yes. Of course. This is the idea. Every call starts anew. It is only the stack and the parameters of the function what's different.

Comment: Please read about [local variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_variable) first. In short the answer is yes, but even if there were no recursions, the answer would still be yes.

Comment: Also keep in mind that the scope of i is not the foo function but the for loop that declares it.

Comment: Also note that in C++, it is possible to use *local static variables*, which do keep their values for each invocation of the function. Anyway, perhaps you should train recursive programming with the SML programming language :)

Answer (score 0):

Yep, every time you call `foo` it starts a whole new for-loop, and therefor with the new looping variable `i`.

Answer (score 0):

Each call to `foo` will start from "fresh", so yes, the loop will always start from `0`. If that's not what you want, then you would have to pass in an argument for "where to start".

Answer (score 0):

Local-scoped variables on each function call will be different references thus they will hold different values/objects.

Usually you pass an argument by reference to the recursive function/method in order to share its value along all recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is not special. It will do it the same as in the first iteration with the exception that the arguments are different. As with other methods the rest of every method is done after the recursive call is finished. Thus your for loop will resume and both  yaddas (...) will be executed in each level of the recursion.